# Measuring the pixel width of a string

Tags: cocoa-touch, graphics, nsstring, width

I need to measure the pixel width of a string in Cocoa Touch. Can anyone point me to a link that explains how to do this?

Comment: You should not ask for a generic objective-c answer when this question is really about features in Cocoa for Mac OS X or Cocoa Touch for iPhone OS. Objective-C is just the programming language, that both Cocoa and Cocoa Touch uses.

Comment: Is there any other use of objective-c besides programming for Mac OS or IOS? If so, is it significant?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On iPhone OS it is slightly different, instead look at the [NSString UIKit Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html). The idea is the same as in Cocoa for Mac OS X, but there are more methods.

For single lines of text use:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font 
              forWidth:(CGFloat)width 
         lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

And for multiline texts use:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font 
     constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size 
         lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

The use of a `UILineBreakMode` as argument for single lines of text can be confusing, but this is because the line break is also used to define how to truncate the text.

Comment: This seems to work fine for usual fonts but it doesn't seem to give the exact bounds for fonts such as Zapfino. Sample code is at http://paste.lisp.org/display/130803 and output screenshot is at http://ScrnSht.com/juixwk. Any idea why and how to solve it?

Comment: deprecated in iOS7.. the docs don't refer to any replacement.. is there any?

Comment: The current iOS7 docs (Xcode 5.0.1) do refer to replacements (which tend to be iOS7-only).

Comment: lineBreakMode options now start with NS.  e.g. NSLineBreakByWordWrapping

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [NSString Application Kit Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html), specifically [`boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:). The value returned by that routine should give you the width of your `NSString`.

Comment: The documentation is not very clear on how to actually use `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:`. It would be nice if you could add an example of how to actually use this method to measure a string with a particular font.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is now deprecated. Check this for iOS 7+

```
 sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode
```

is deprecated now. Use below code snippet,

```
UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16.f];

NSString *name = @"APPLE";

CGSize size = [name sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];
```