# UILabel fit issues

Tags: ios, uilabel

I use this method for recalculate frame for my labels:

```
- (void)fitElements {    
    CGFloat currentX = 0.0;
    CGFloat currentY = 0.0;    
    for (UIView *view in elements) {    
        CGRect rect = view.frame;
        rect.origin.x = currentX;
        rect.origin.y = currentY;        
        currentX = rect.origin.x + rect.size.width + 5;        
        view.frame = rect;      
        if (currentX >= 420) {
            currentX = 0.0;
            currentY += rect.size.height + 5;
        }
    }
}
```

If my label crosses the border that more than 420 I move my object to next line.

```
- (void)createElements {
    NSInteger tag = 0;
    for (NSString *str in words) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [self addGesture:label];
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        label.text = str;
        [label setAlpha:0.8];
        [label sizeToFit];
        [elements addObject:label];
    }
}
```

This is how it looks if I create object as above (using `[label sizeToFit];`)

[image]

as we can see all my label went out of border

but if I use label with hardcode frame I get this:

[image]

and this is what I want, but in this case I have static width of object.

This is my method with a hardcode frame.

```
- (void)createElements {
    NSInteger tag = 0;
    for (NSString *str in words) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [self addGesture:label];
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        label.text = str;
        [label setAlpha:0.8];
        [label setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
        [elements addObject:label];
        tag++;
    }
}
```

How can I make object with relative width and that it also can recalculates correctly?

Comment: You could try using [method from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3429732/653513) instead of `[label sizeToFit];`

Comment: yes the same result maybe i need to set UIFont in any case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve something like left-justify with small modification of your code:

```
- (void)fitElements {
CGFloat currentX = 0.0;
CGFloat currentY = 0.0;
for (UILabel *view in elements) { //UIView changed to UILabel
    CGRect rect = view.frame;
    rect.origin.x = currentX;
    rect.origin.y = currentY;
    rect.size.width = [self widthOfString: view.text withFont:view.font];
    currentX = rect.origin.x + rect.size.width + 5;
    view.frame = rect;
    if (currentX + rect.size.width >= 420) {   //EDIT done here
        currentX = 0.0;
        currentY += rect.size.height + 5;
        rect.origin.x = currentX;
        rect.origin.y = currentY;
        view.frame = rect;
        currentX = rect.origin.x + rect.size.width + 5;
    }
}}

- (CGFloat)widthOfString:(NSString *)string withFont:(NSFont *)font {
     NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
     return [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes] size].width;
 }
```

`widthOfString` method is copied from [Stephen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3429732/653513)

**EDIT:**

You can also find a lot of useful methods dealing with size of graphical representation of a string in [NSString UIKit Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: sorry I have copy paste and it does not work as well :( I don't need grouped or table style, I'm wanna the same variant as on first image, but that all words contain in frame.

Comment: of course, sorry for that. i edited the code. have a xp machine here, so i couldn't test it. now it should work.

Comment: thanks, but I have corrected your code, cause if we don't increase values of currentX in if block in the next iteration we get the same value and labels add on each other.

Comment: i don't what the problem but it is don't work, but it work if I don't use [label sizeToFit]; how come :(

Comment: don't use `sizeToFit` - it's `UIView`'s method - it changes it's bounds to fit all the subviews. It has nothing to do with fitting the string to a `UILabel` since characters (string) are not considered as subviews.

Comment: i edited the answer some more but can't test it at the moment - if there are some subviews that are not of UILabel type this will crash - but it's easy to adapt for that situation

Comment: so wich method i should to use for get dynamic width of UILabel

Comment: no problem. you should uncheck the answer if it still doesn't work