# Is there a way to get the measurements of \t in an NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

If this is a repeat, let me know and I'll remove it immediately--I've had the devil of a time searching for the answer, since "\t" returns searches without the forward slash.

I need to find the width of an NSString that contains begins with `\t\t` .  Using `sizeWithFont` doesn't do it, since it just ignores the space.  Is there a way to measure how much space the tab takes up?

Comment: Have your tried with NSAttributedString?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429671/how-to-get-the-width-of-an-nsstring

Comment: No.  I haven't used NSAttributedString before, but an initial glance at the documentation doesn't make it immediately clear to me how I could use it to accomplish this.  Do you have any specific thoughts about what I could do with NSAttributedString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what your code was but this seemed to work for me.

```
NSString *delMessage = @"\t";
CGSize theSize = [delMessage sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter" size:30]];
NSLog(@"length %f",theSize.width);
```

> log was length 8.000000

```
NSString *delMessage = @"\t\t";
CGSize theSize = [delMessage sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter" size:30]];
NSLog(@"length %f",theSize.width);
```

> log was length 16.000000

Comment: Well, that was easy.  Whoops.  I think my problem was that I'd been measuring a `UITextView`'s `sizeWithFont` and, when it didn't take the `\t` into account, assumed that that applied to `NSString` as well.  Just goes to show you--never make even the most basic assumptions!