# how can I increase the size of cell in UITableViewController at run time when the text to be entered in the cell is large?

Tags: ios

I am loading data into a UITableviewcell from a server and the problem is that sometimes the text returned is large and sometimes less . Now the problem is when large text is returned , the tableview cell is not able to display the whole data , and when the text returned is small , then there is a blank space in the cell which does not look good.

Can someone help me in this matter please ?

Comment: Hey, check out - tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: of UITableViewDelegate and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429671/how-to-get-the-width-of-an-nsstring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do your own height calculations.  Let Auto Layout (and self-sizing cells) do the work.

Here's [an excellent walkthrough covering what to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/4151918), from a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is being displayed in a `UITextView`, you can use the `sizeThatFits()` method or `contentSize` property to determine the size of the text. You can do this in the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to apply the size of the text to the `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property estimatedRowHeight for tableView in iOS 8.

```
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
```