# ios how to autoresize uilabel's height when text is added OR deleted (and numberOfLines = 0)

Tags: iphone, ios, resize, height, uilabel

I have a UILabel that displays a user's "bio". I also have the user able to edit this text by having a uitextview pop up upon a user tap and then once the user is done adding or removing text from this uitextview, i say label.text = textview.text, so it updates the bio label's text.
*However, I want a way of telling the label to fix it's height according to how much text was added or removed.* Is there a way of doing this? Thank you in advance!

NathanF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CGRect labelFrame = label.frame;
labelFrame.size = [textview.text sizeWithFont:label.font
                            constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
label.frame = labelFrame;
```

This will resize the label (height) according to the new text (while respecting font and linebreakmode).

NOTE: UILineBreakMode has been deprecated as of 6.0. Use NSLineBreak instead.

[Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UILineBreakMode)

Answer (score 4):

call

```
[labelName sizeToFit];
```

after setting the new text. Also make sure you set word wrap or character wrap like so:

```
[labelName setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

or

```
[labelName setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];
```

Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: thank you. this totally works, but one of my criteria was keeping the same width.

Answer (score 1):

This method "**sizeWithFont**" is deprecated in iOS 7 instead of this you can use the method below:

```
CGRect rect = [YourText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(labelWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       context:nil];
 NSLog(@"Height: %f",rect.size.height);
```

For more info look into: [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize%3aoptions%3aattributes%3acontext%3a)

Comment: I get [__NSCFConstantString pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance after using the above code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSString sizeWithFont:...] to measure text for use in a label.

See also: [How to get the size of a NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669063/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-nsstring)