# Autoresizing UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I wan to know how can I resize my table view cell, and see all the message
My app is obtaining the messages from an xml on my server, and then it shows them, but if the message is longer than the text field it just display 3 dots
here is my code:

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)myTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return ( messages == nil ) ? 0 : [messages count];
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 37;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.messageList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChatListItem"];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatListItem" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UILabel *textLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
textLabel.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"text"];
UILabel *stextLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
stextLabel.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"text"];

UILabel *userLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
userLabel.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"user"];
UILabel *suserLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
suserLabel.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"user"];

if ([usernameText.text isEqualToString:userLabel.text]){
    UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chat1@2x.png"]];
    [cell setBackgroundView:img];
    [img release];

    textLabel.hidden=NO;
    stextLabel.hidden=YES;

    userLabel.hidden=NO;
    suserLabel.hidden = YES;


}
else{
    UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chat2@2x.png"]];
    [cell setBackgroundView:img];
    [img release];

    textLabel.hidden=YES;
    stextLabel.hidden=NO;

    userLabel.hidden=YES;
    suserLabel.hidden = NO;
}

return cell;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to reduce font size or you do you want to have text in more lines?

Comment: yep more lines but making bigger the cell

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass by heightForRowAtIndexPath like this logic (isn't a code ready):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"text"];
if(text is larger then what ever you want) {
    return yourSpecificCellHeight;
}
return 37;
```

}

To calculate the size of text see [this post on stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669063/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-nsstring)