# Auto resize the text size of a MULTILINE UILabel

Tags: ios, resize, uilabel

I want to auto resize the text size of a UILabel with numberOfLines>1. The UILabel width and height have to be fix. Is there a better solution instead of counting the characters and setting the size manualy? I am using iOS6.

Comment: Please refer <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669063/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-nsstring">this previous SO answer</a>

Comment: see http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/how-to-multiline-label-ios-objective-c/

Comment: you can do it programmatically, the iOS does not adjust the font size for the multiline `UILabel` views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified a solution I found. This can be used now in a UITableViewCell:

```
- (void)resizeFontForLabel:(UILabel*)aLabel maxSize:(int)maxSize minSize:(int)minSize lblWidth: (float)lblWidth lblHeight: (float)lblHeight {
    // use font from provided label so we don't lose color, style, etc
    UIFont *font = aLabel.font;

    // start with maxSize and keep reducing until it doesn't clip
    for(int i = maxSize; i >= minSize; i--) {
        font = [font fontWithSize:i];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(lblWidth, MAXFLOAT);

//        NSString* string = [aLabel.text stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
        CGSize labelSize = [aLabel.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:aLabel.lineBreakMode];

        if(labelSize.height <= lblHeight)
            break;
    }

    // Set the UILabel's font to the newly adjusted font.
    aLabel.font = font;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below line of code will give you the full size of the string:

```
CGSize labelSize = [labelString sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:label.contentSize];
```