# how to create button from title string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uibutton

I want create UIButton from NSString.
I have one string like this **@"First Button"** I want first get size of width pixel and after create one Button According to this string but I don't know about it.

please guide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the size of a NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669063/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-nsstring)

Comment: @Lucas That's not the best duplicate since the answer uses a now deprecated method.

Comment: @rmaddy That's fine, let's reference this one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18897897/426959

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `CGSize` of `NSString` using `sizeWithAttributes` (before we used `sizeWithFont` but this is now deprecated method with `iOS 7`) and then create `UIButton` according to the size like

```
NSString *string = @"First Button";

CGSize size = [string sizeWithAttributes:
               @{NSFontAttributeName:
                     [UIFont systemFontOfSize:27.0f]}];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, size.width, size.height);
button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[button setTitle:string forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Review this working fine for me.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: You left out the important part being asked in the question - how to determine the string size.

Comment: Yeah, you can use sizeWithAttributes review the update answer

Answer (score 1):

First you have to get the size of the text by using

```
NSString someText = @"some Text";
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(youMaxWidthForButton, youMaxHeightForButton);
CGRect labelSize = [someText boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont     systemFontOfSize:17.0f]} context:nil];
```

than you create your `UIButton`

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:labelSize];
```

finally you set the button title

```
 button.titleLabel.text = someText;
```

Comment: my friend what is constraintSize?

Comment: this is the max value for width and height. For example you dont want your button to be bigger than your iphones width in portrait mode.. then you use `320` for the max width