# Why is so much extra space being added to my UILabel when I try to change height to fit text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have no idea why the height of my `UILabel` is expanding to such a great height. It leaves the text of my `UILabel` in the centre. I don't want all of this extra space...

Unwanted extra space

[image]

Here is my code (I set the text before this point):

```
self.infoDescription.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.infoDescription sizeToFit];
self.infoDescription.frame = CGRectMake(20, self.infoAdultSize.frame.size.height+self.infoAdultSize.frame.origin.y+10, self.infoView.frame.size.width-40, self.infoDescription.frame.size.height);
```

Please help :( I just want the height of the `UILabel` to fit the text exactly.

Comment: just try to interchange the code of label, first set the frame and then make size to fit of label.

Comment: That worked! Thank you.

Comment: please upvote my answer if helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the size of a NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669063/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-nsstring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First set the frame and then make size to fit of label.**

```
  **self.infoDescription.frame = CGRectMake(20, self.infoAdultSize.frame.size.height+self.infoAdultSize.frame.origin.y+10, self.infoView.frame.size.width-40, self.infoDescription.frame.size.height);
    [self.infoDescription sizeToFit];**
```

Comment: Wow, It's Working fluently.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(300, 9999);
NSString *myString = @"This is a long string which wraps";
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
CGSize myStringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:myFont 
                           constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                               lineBreakMode:self.myLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

([original source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2669131/2177402))

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text) it works for me and it is exactly what you are looking for.

```
//Calculate the expected size based on the font and linebreak mode of your label
// FLT_MAX here simply means no constraint in height
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296, FLT_MAX);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];   

//adjust the label the the new height.
CGRect newFrame = yourLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
yourLabel.frame = newFrame;
```