# Custom cell with UITextView: autosize width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a problem with a chat functionality that I'm trying to implement.
Each row is a custom cell. The custom cell is initialized from xib file and has an UIView, and inside it there is a `UITextview` and a `UIButton`.

The problem: I always have the same width in my rows (cells) and I want them to adapt to the content. The height is ok (I use "heightForRowAtIndexPath").
I tried setting the frame in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with the following:

```
cell.message.frame = CGRectMake(cell.message.frame.origin.x, cell.message.frame.origin.y, MyNewRect.size.height, MyNewRect.size.height);
```

(By the way: cell.message is the UITextView)

I searched in other StackOverflow Questions but nothing really helped me. Maybe the problem is the container but I don't know how to resize both of them.

Edit:
I add my XIB image and the constraints.
[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using Auto Layout? you should play with the constraints, you could calculate the size of the string, have a max width in order to go to new line

Comment: Yes, i've used AutoLayout in the xib. And thats actually happening. The problem is that if i send something short like "ok" the size of the container is the same (almost all the width) and i dont know how to adjust that width, not the height.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669063/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-nsstring here is an example of how you could calculate the size of the text, you could use this to adjust your constraints

Comment: What do you mean by **the problem is the container**? And can you give a screenshot of the xib file with your constraints?

Comment: Yes, there is my xib and constraints

Comment: what is your iOS deployment target?