# Search visualization using UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, search, core-data, uilabel

I have a goal to implement local search inside Core Data entities. Technical part of finding occurrences is pretty clear. But I'm not sure how to display it correctly. Case: we have string in our entity

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor

and user want to find entries with word `adipiscing`. We have `UILabel` with width i.e. 320dp and `numberOfLines = 1`. If we will display whole string without correct trimming it would be

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec...

which just useless for user. I want label to look like

> ...consectetur **adipiscing** elit, se...

So in other words I want search occurrence to be "focused" somewhere about middle of `UILabel`. How can I trim the string where occurrence has happened depending on label font and width?

Answer (score 0):

It's not complete, but should bring you on track:

```
let wholeString = "This is a very long Hello world in a simple String"
let someSearch = wholeString.range(of: "Hello")!

// Make sure to call dropLast() twice to remove the space before 'Hello'
var stringBeforeSomeSearch = wholeString[wholeString.startIndex...someSearch.lowerBound].dropLast().dropLast()

// This is everything before the searched string
let prefixRange = stringBeforeSomeSearch.range(of: " ", options: .backwards)!.upperBound...someSearch.lowerBound

print(wholeString[prefixRange]) // prints "long H"
print(wholeString[prefixRange.lowerBound...someSearch.upperBound]) // prints "long Hello "
```

If you need more explanation, I'll be back later on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses UITextView instead of UILabel, to achieve the desired search visualisation.

The concept is to use a UITextView with userInteraction and vertical scroll disabled and horizontal scroll enabled.
Use the textView method of scroll to range to show the desired word.

```
let textView = UITextView()
textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
textView.contentSize = CGSize(width: textWidth, height: textView.frame.size.width)
scrollTo(text: "swift")


func scrollTo(text: String) {
    if let string = textView.text,
        let range = string.localizedStandardRange(of: text) {
        let viewRange = NSRange(range, in: string)
        textView.scrollRangeToVisible(viewRange)
    }
}
```

textWidth is the width of your total text. Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669063/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-nsstring/2669131#2669131) for help.