# Finding the number of lines in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uitextview

I'm using `UIScrollView` in which I have placed a `UIImageView` and a `UITextView`. I make the `UIScrollView` to scroll both the images and text and it works fine, but my `UITextView` contains dynamic text (i.e number of lines is different for each time). So I can't find the way to assign contentSize of `UITextView`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calculate the text width and define your text view width using below code

```
+(float) calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(NSString *) text: (UIFont *)withFont: (float)width
:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
{

[text retain];
[withFont retain];
CGSize suggestedSize = [text sizeWithFont:withFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(215, 1000) lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];

[text release];
[withFont release];

return suggestedSize.height;
}
```

and use when you want to display dynamic text as

```
float titleHeight;

titleHeight = [Your view controllre ViewController calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"title"]] :[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]:300 :UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
```

give this titleHeight to your textview or do calculation dividation using titleheight ,you can get the number of lines

If you get problem then reply

Answer (score 1):

[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669063/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-nsstring) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435544/measuring-the-pixel-width-of-a-string-in-objective-c) might help you.
You can put a condition that if width of the new CGSize is greater than textview width then number of lines = 2 else 1.