# Can the size for -[NSString drawInRect:] be determined by the string's content?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, graphics, nsstring

I have a long string called `theString` in my code, which I'm passing to the `drawRect:` method to draw on screen.

```
    -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    [theString drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 200)]; 
}
```

As you can see, I can just set the width to the screen size, but the height has to be set manually, which is a problem when the strings being passed are of differing lengths. How do I automatically detect the height the frame needs to be? Also in the future I may be extending this to include an attributed string of differing font styles, so counting characters may not be a very good option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Measuring the pixel width of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435544/measuring-the-pixel-width-of-a-string)

Comment: I dont think that will help me as the attributed string will have different fonts, styles, etc. Am i right?

Comment: If you're specifically asking about using an `NSAttributedString`, then please edit your question to reflect that. There's a similar method: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688-CH1-SW7

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is get the font that your text will have

```
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SOME_NAME" size:16];
```

And then use `NSString`'s method `sizeWithFont:`, like so:

```
CGSize theStringSize = [theString sizeWithFont:myFont];
```

Finally, set your string's width and height:

```
[theString drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, theStringSize.width, theStringSize.height)];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea unfortunately thats my issue, the text will eventually be a full page of text layed out with headings, different sized fonts, etc so using the sizeWithFont wont work properly will it?

Answer (score -1):

you can do it by `RTLabel`. Download from this link [RTLabel.h](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel/blob/master/RTLabelProject/Classes/RTLabel.h)

[RTLabel.m](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel/blob/master/RTLabelProject/Classes/RTLabel.m)

> use it by:
>   set text to `RTLabel` object, it will handel `HTML` string also and get size of `RTLabel` object, it will be the size of your text.