# IOS - Get height NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring

How i can get height absolutely of `NSString`, because I'm trying to do the following:

```
NSString *text = "Hello word, i'm a programer";
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(300, 9999);

UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];

CGSize myStringSize = [text sizeWithFont:myFont
                       constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                           lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

NSLog(@"myStringSize %f",myStringSize.height);
```

I find it in [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669063/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-nsstring/2669131#2669131) but I think it do not ok.

Comment: One does not simply "get height" of `NSString`.

Comment: Do you want to get the height of a Label?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669063/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-nsstring?lq=1

Comment: "Fix my code" issues have no future use when there are numerous working examples.

Comment: WrightsCS: How do you get them?

Comment: parilogic: I'm running it, but result's not ok

Comment: You're missing the "@" before the text, and secondly, what do you mean by "not ok"? Does it crash? Does it produce a wrong result? In that case, what is the result and what did you expect?

Comment: @Can: "not ok" is mean :The result return height in my NSLog above not true

Comment: @BlueSky So "not ok" means "not true", gotcha. Buddy, you need to tell  us the output of the NSLog, and how much did you expect it should be. I don't know what "not true" or "not ok" means to you.

Comment: @Can: thank you for enthusiasm, in my code I showed NSLOG and result return is "eg: 310", this is number height of NSString, of course number's incorrect, actualy it only "90" or "120", I use to manual canculate.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(300, 9999);
NSString *myString = @"This is a long string which wraps";
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
CGSize myStringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:myFont 
                       constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                           lineBreakMode:self.myLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

Your code isn't working because you are not using an NSString!

Comment: and if you are trying to use core graphics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435544/measuring-the-pixel-width-of-a-string