# Calculate NSString size to adjust UITextField frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield

I have issues calculating the accurate size of a NSString displayed in a UITextField.

My goal is to update the textfield frame size according to the string size programmatically (without using *sizeToFit*). I am using the **sizeWithFont** function.

```
-(void)resizeTextFieldAccordingToText:(NSString*)textFieldString {

    CGPoint originalCenter = self.textField.center;

    UIFont* currentFont = [textField font];
    CGSize newSize = [textFieldString sizeWithFont:currentFont];

    //Same incorrect results with the extended version of sizeWithFont, e.g.
    //[textFieldString sizeWithFont:currentFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300.0, 100.0) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];

    [self.textField setFrame:(CGRectMake(self.textField.frame.origin.x, self.textField.frame.origin.y, newSize.width, newSize.height))];
    [self.textField setCenter:originalCenter];

}
```

Problem: While this return correct size results at first its becomes more and more unprecise by adding characters therefore finally starts clipping the string (as seen in the right screenshot).

[image]

How do I get the accurate size of the textField string for correctly adjusting its size?

Comment: May be this post could be useful for your purposes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435544/measuring-the-pixel-width-of-a-string

Comment: I am aware of this but even using this extended version of sizeWithFont (e.g. CGSize newSize = [textFieldString sizeWithFont:currentFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300.0, 100.0) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];) does return the same slightly incorrect sizes.

Comment: yes, because it doesn't account for padding

Comment: When are you resizing your text field? Remember that the delegate method `-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` gets called _before_ the text field's text actually changes, so if you calculate your new size there, you need to build the modified text using `NSString`'s `-stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:`. Otherwise, your size will always be one character "late".

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you don't take into account the contentInset of the UITextField. Your code would be fine for a label not for a textfield.

**for example: one way could be:**

```
CGPoint originalCenter = self.textField.center;

UIFont* currentFont = [textField font];
CGSize oldSize = [self.textField.text sizeWithFont:currentFont];
CGSize newSize = [textFieldString sizeWithFont:currentFont];

CGRect finalFrame = self.textField.frame
finalFrame.size.width -= oldSize.width;
finalFrame.size.width += newSize.width;
finalFrame.size.height -= oldSize.height;
finalFrame.size.height += newSize.height;
[self.textField setFrame:finalFrame];

[self.textField setCenter:originalCenter];
```

ios7 deprecates `sizeWithFont:currentFont` so it is `sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:currentFont}`

Comment: written inline, not tested -- but the principles should become clear: the size isn't only that of the string

Answer (score 1):

UITextField has it's own layout inside if you use borderStyle != UITextBorderStyleNone. In this case you have to increase text size dimensions by some constants.

With UITextBorderStyleNone you don't have this problem, and code below works like a charm (iOS 7 introduced new method to get text size, -sizeWithFont: is deprecated)

```
- (IBAction)textChanged:(UITextField *)field
{
    UIFont *font = field.font;
    NSString *string = field.text;

    CGSize size = [string sizeWithAttributes:
            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName]];

    CGPoint center = field.center;
    CGRect frame = field.frame;
    frame.size = size; // or CGSizeMake(size.width + WIDTH_PADDING * 2, size.height + HEIGHT_PADDING * 2)
    field.frame = frame;
    field.center = center;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem remains. A static padding doesn't help. I would need to adjust the padding with every string change because the precision of sizeWithFont changes with each character changed.

Comment: Which font do you use? I have tried several standard fonts - no clipping, everything seems to be ok

Comment: Hmm. That's puzzling. In my example I used a non-system font (font-family: "SourceSansPro-ExtraLight"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 38.00pt). However when I use the default font (font-family: ".HelveticaNeueInterface-M3"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt) I have the very same issue.

Comment: in my answer I address the same issue but I don't care about what border style is used.

Comment: still - this sounds reasonable when you have NO border. I dislike constants :D